# Handshake Failed test connectivity for OpenVPN

Tags: server, client, vpn, openvpn, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to set up OpenVPN on Ubuntu 20.04. I'm not experienced in this area. After I set up OpenVPN, I perform test connectivity. I received handshake error message:

```
Sun Jul 26 05:53:17 2020 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]68.228.217.219:1194
Sun Jul 26 05:53:17 2020 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Sun Jul 26 05:53:17 2020 UDP link local: (not bound)
Sun Jul 26 05:53:17 2020 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]My_Public_ISP_IP:1194
Sun Jul 26 05:54:17 2020 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Sun Jul 26 05:54:17 2020 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Sun Jul 26 05:54:17 2020 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Sun Jul 26 05:54:17 2020 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

Then I check to log

```
journalctl --identifier openvpn
```

I found two error message I believe why my OpenVPN cannot connect:

1. This is one of the error messages:

   Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
2. I notice it's using my old client .conf file:
   [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoUOP.png)

My new .conf file is local.ovpn/

I tried removing client conf. `sudo rm -vf BigK`  and replace it with local.ovpn. but it didnt work.

I need help figuring this issue out. i tried researching on my own but i came up short.

***UPDATE***

After several hours of researching online. the closet post I see helping me is this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385966/openvpn-error-status-2-and-cant-connect-to-internet-while-usingwhich didn't help.

I checked my client.conf

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote Public_IP 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
verb 3
<ca>
```

Here is my server.conf

```
local IP
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
```

Here is localvpn.ovpn

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote Public_IP 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
verb 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and didn't find any solution. I was looking for another way to connect to OpenVPN server and it helped me.

Ubuntu 20.04 has a default tool for using OpenVPN:

1. `Settings -> Network`
2. Click `+` icon on one line with the VPN title
3. Choose `Import from file...` option and select your `.ovpn` config file in the popup window
4. Click `Add` button and that's it

PS: I hope it will help somebody to save any hours